# Checking coercivity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-derivatives

I want to make sure my reasoning is correct:
Recall first that a bilinear form $a : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a normed space $V$ is coercive if $$a(u,u) \geq c\|u\|_V^2,$$for some $c > 0$.

I have the following bilinear form $a(u,v) = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx$ on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. I want to show $a$ is coercive: Notice that $$a(u,u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx = \| \nabla u\|_2^2.$$Now, since $\Omega$ is bounded we have the Poincaré inequality that tell us that the norm $\| \nabla u\|_2$ is equivalent to the norm $\|u\|_{H^1}$, hence on $H^1_0$. So there's some constant $c > 0$ such that $$\|\nabla u\|_2^2 \geq c\|u\|^2_{H^10}.$$So we have $$a(u,u) \geq c\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2.$$

If we now consider the bilinear form $$b(u,v) = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v + uvdx,$$then $$b(u,u) = \|\nabla u\|_2^2 + \|u\|_2^2 \geq \|u\|_{H^1_0}.$$

This shows that both bilinear forms are coercive.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: You don't need the extra step and say that $a(u,u) \geq c \Vert u \Vert^2_{H^1}$, since, as you said, $\Vert \nabla\cdot \Vert_{L^2}$ provides a norm on $H^1_0(\Omega)$. As for the bilinear form $b$, you're missing a square in the last inequality and possibly a constant on the right-hand side (depending on how you're defining $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{H^1}$).

Comment: @stange yeah that's true, was as typo! thank you